# How do I unlock all the special Kairobots?

Tags: kairobotica

In Kairobotica, you can research various items, and you get either a special Kairobot, another item, something you can sell in your gift shops, or useless junk.

I find that the special Kairobots are super useful, and I love knowing what they are and what they do.

What items do I need to research to unlock each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now gotten all the Kairobots, with the exception of Sally Prin.

```
Name                Item  
Mini-Kairobot       Gold Cardboard  
Kairo Devil         Bat Wings
Dapper Kairo        Silk Hat
kPhone 5            Mobile Phone
Kairo Driller       Old Tool
Kairo Ninja         Shuriken
Kairo Crystal       Crystal
Kairo Missile       Rocket
Kairo Tank          Firework
Dr. Kairo           Syringe
Kairoman            Cheap Kerchief
Kairo Samurai       Rusty Sword
Papa Kairo          Pretty Table
Kairo King          Crown
Kairovsky           Fake Mustache   
Kairo Express       Heavy Wheels
Geeky Kairobot      Thick Glasses
Swan Kairobot       Swan Statue
Kairotaro           Samurai Wig
Kairo Angel         Dove Wings
----------------------------------------------
Sally Prin          Clear all locations need to be completely clear and become
                    a friend of all, including the district where there is no 
                    special security
```

Comment: I reeeeeeally want to know what "Beautiful Flipping the Table" means.